# Top level errors in network socket program

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a program to work with network sockets instead of unix ones. I'm not sure if it's header files or incorrect usage of functions and header files. Programs will send and print messages to screen until user enters "quit" using network sockets. Trying to compile this server one produces many errors, even though my client one compiles.

Updated...

Errors ("main" and top level ones):

```
server02.c:37:5: error: 'server_socket' undeclared (first use in this   
function)

server02.c:37:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for 
each function it appears in

server02.c:41:26: error: 'struct sockaddr_in' has no member named 'sin_path'

server02.c:94:252: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token

server02.c:95:253: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token

server02.c:98:264: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 
string constant

server02.c:99:259: warning: data definition has no type or storage class 
[enabled by default]

server02.c:99:259: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'close' 
[enabled by default]

server02.c:99:259: warning: parameter names (without types) in function 
declaration [enabled by default]

server02.c:100:261: warning: data definition has no type or storage class 
[enabled by default]

server02.c:100:261: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 
'close' [enabled by default]

server02.c:100:261: warning: parameter names (without types) in function 
declaration [enabled by default]

server02.c:101:263: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'return'

server02.c:103:263: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
```

Code for server one(client one compiles)...

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <sys/un.h> //not needed anymore b/c in, not unix?
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
//ADDING THESE HELP, BUT STILL ERRORS
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#define PORT 50014
#define LEN 256
#define SOCKET_NAME "server_socket"

int main(void)
{
//some may not be needed
  char buf[LEN];
  int server_sockfd;
  int client_sockfd;
  socklen_t client_len;
  ssize_t num_client_bytes;
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  struct sockaddr_in client_address;

  //create new
  server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if(-1 == server_sockfd)
    {
    perror("server -- socket failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  //bind new
  memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_socket.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  strcpy(server_address.sun_path, SOCKET_NAME);//not sure if needed

  if(bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
                                  sizeof(server_address)))
   {
    perror("server -- bind failed");
   }

 //create connection q and wait for client
  if(listen(server_sockfd, 5))
    {
     perror("server-- listen failed");
    }

  //announce server is waiting for client connection
  puts("server waiting...");

  //accept connection
  client_len = sizeof(client_address);
  client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address,
                                                            &client_len);

   //LOOP AND SEND MESSAGE HERE

  //close stuff
  close(client_sockfd);
  close(server_sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the Internet socket headers:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
```

Comment: This helped a lot, but I've still got a few errors. 'server_socket' undeclared and 'struct sockaddr_in' has no member named 'sin_path'

Comment: `sin_path`  is not a standard field in Internet socket addresses, could that be something left from when you used Unix sockets?

Comment: I got rid of that part, but I've still got a ton of top level (?) errors. May need to recheck the man pages and see if these errors are covered?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

When you define a macro

```
#define a b
```

that means where-ever compiler see's a, it should replace with b. in your code you've done something like that

```
#define SOCKET_NAME "server_socket"
```

Buth what is ***server_socket*** ? may be you meant **server_address**, am getting this cus in the section *#bind new* 3rd line

```
server_socket.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
```

this is the correct syntax

```
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
```

also fix the the macro(***server_socket***?)

```
#define SOCKET_NAME "server_socket"
```